# How to append column to a specific row in Cassandra

Tags: concurrency, cassandra

It seems like each column needs a name, and will be stored in the order implied by the name you give it.

What if I don't care about the name, as long as it gets appended to the existing columns (such that it will appear after all the ones that existed at the time the insertion happened)?

In effect, I'm asking for an atomic auto_increment column name, so that I can guarantee that concurrent attempts to append columns will not step on each other's toes, and all appear near the end of the column list (so a UUID name isn't really want I want).

The use case is effectively a log (for a specific key, so I want this to stay within a particular row) that will be updated comparatively rarely, but could be done concurrently. If I just use timestamps as column names, there's a slight chance of two concurrent edits using the same timestamp and data loss, which I don't want to happen.

Is such a thing possible in Cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use TimeUUIDType.  It is time ordered and comprises:

- A timestamp (resolution 100 ns)
- A random component to avoid collisions (with very high probability)
- The generator's MAC address to avoid collisions across machines.

If you want to always get the latest columns you could wrap it with ReversedType to make it more efficient.